# Why do I get "Response was not JSON" on the Rust Playground?

Tags: rust

I am trying to run a simple hello world program on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/):

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}
```

But all I get is an error:

```
Response was not JSON: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.
```

What is going on?

Comment: I get it, too. I think Rust Playground is broken.

Comment: [This version works](https://play.integer32.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be the symptomatic message displayed if the server-side of the Rust Playground is unresponsive, likely due to either updates or overloaded usage. There isn't much you can do beyond waiting for it to become responsive.

There is a mirror site [here](https://play.integer32.com/) (by the playground's primary developer).

Comment: It's weird that Rust is all about great errors and telling you carefully how to fix your code, but once the Rust Playground is overloaded all you get is "Response is not JSON".